# How to link three tables?

Tags: sql, firebird

I'm new to SQL and ask for your help.
There are 3 tables, these are `"Employees"`, `"Positions"` and `"EmployeesPositions"`.
For example, 2 `positions` can be attached to one `employee`.
How to link tables so that duplicates do not occur? I read about foreign keys and *JOIN*, but I have not yet figured out how to do it correctly.

Table structure:
 `Employees (id, Name);`
 `Positions (id, Post, Rate);` `EmployeesPositions` - I do not know how to make it right.

What I need: when adding an employee to the `"Employees"` table, associate an entry with posts from the `"Positions"` table, but as I wrote above, one employee can be associated with 2 posts (but not always). How correctly to implement the third table (EmployeesPositions), because in Positions only posts and rates are stored, and in EmployeesPositions there should be records, for example, Name1 => Post1 and Post2, and Name2 only Post 1?

If I thought something wrong, tell me please how best to implement it.

Comment: Is 2 positions the maximum, or just illustrative (in other words: can an employee have more than two positions?)

Comment: Employee can have two positions maximum

Comment: @AtulStha Don't propose edits that removes a relevant tag (Firebird) and replaces it with an irrelevant tag (MySQL). If the question is about the Firebird database system, it is not about MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to solve your problem, each with their own pros and cons.

First if we simplify your problem to "an employee has zero or more positions", then you can use the following table to associate an employee with a position:

```
create table employeespositions (
    employee_id integer not null,
    position_id integer not null,
    constraint pk_employeespositions 
        primary key (employee_id, position_id),
    constraint fk_employeespositions_employee 
        foreign key (employee_id) references employees (id),
    constraint fk_employeespositions_position 
        foreign key (position_id) references positions (id)
)
```

The foreign keys enforce the existence of the employee and the position, while the primary key ensures a combination of employee and position only exists once.

This solution has two downsides:

1. It does not enforce that an employee has at least one position
2. It allows an employee to have more than two positions

The second problem is easily fixed by adding a trigger that checks if there is at most 1 position for an employee when attempting to insert (this allows a maximum of two):

```
create exception tooManyPositions 'Too many positions for employee';

set term #;
recreate trigger employeespositions_bi 
    active before insert on employeespositions
as
    declare position_count integer;
begin
    select count(*) 
        from employeespositions 
        where employee_id = new.employee_id 
        into position_count;
    if (position_count > 1) then
        exception tooManyPositions;
end#
set term ;#
```

However this solution does not enforce that an employee has at least one position. You could add a `before delete` trigger that ensures that the last position cannot be deleted, but that does not ensure that a newly created employee has at least one position. If you want to enforce that, you may want to consider using stored procedures for inserting and updating employees and their positions, and have the code of those stored procedures enforce that (eg by requiring a position when creating an employee).

Alternatively, you could also consider denormalizing your design, and making the positions part of the `employees` record, where the employee has a 'primary' and (optionally) a 'secondary' position.

```
create table employees (
    -- using Firebird 3 identity column, change if necessary
    id integer generated by default as identity primary key,
    name varchar(100),
    primary_position_id integer not null,
    secondary_position_id integer,
    constraint fk_employees_primary_position 
        foreign key (primary_position_id) references positions (id),
    constraint fk_employees_secondary_position 
        foreign key (secondary_position_id) references positions (id),
    constraint chk_no_duplicate_position 
        check (secondary_position_id <> primary_position_id)
)
```

The `not null` constraint on `primary_position_id` enforces the existence of this position, while the check constraint prevents assignment of the same position to both columns. Optionally you could consider adding a `before insert or update` trigger that when `primary_position_id` is set `null`, will set it to the value of `secondary_position_id` and sets `secondary_position_id` to `null`.

This solution has the advantage of allowing the enforcement of the existence of a primary position, but may lead to additional complexities when querying positions. This disadvantage can be overcome by creating a view:

```
create view employeespositions
as
    select id as employee_id, primary_position_id as position_id
    from employees
    union all
    select id as employee_id, secondary_position_id as position_id
    from employees
    where secondary_position_id is not null;
```

This view can then be used as if it is a table (although you can't insert into it).